# What is the best way to place 2 buttons and a search bar on the same bar, such that they fill the line?

Tags: html, css

What is the best way to place 2 buttons and a search bar on the same bar, such that they fill the line?
This is where I left off, but I believe I was approaching it very wrong

```html
<div class="panel-heading">
  <div style="float:left;vertical-align: center;">
    <a type="button" class="btn btn-info">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-erase"></span><b> Search</b>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div style="float:right;">
    <a type="button" class="btn btn-warning">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-erase"></span><b> Clear</b>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div style="overflow: hidden;padding: 1em;">
    <input type="text" value="Enter your search here..." ng-model="searchText" style="width: 100%;"></input>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're targeting reasonably current browsers, this sort of thing is pretty much exactly why `flexbox` exists:

```css
.panel-heading {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
}
.panel-heading > div {
  /* This is just so you can see what's going on: */
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 0.5em
}
.panel-heading .stretchy {
  flex-grow: 1;
  -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
}
.panel-heading .stretchy input {
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<br><br><br>
<div class="panel-heading">
  <div>
    <a type="button" class="btn btn-info">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-erase"></span><b> Search</b>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="stretchy">
    <input type="text" value="Enter your search here..." ng-model="searchText"></input>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a type="button" class="btn btn-warning">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-erase"></span><b> Clear</b>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

No you were doing it right, your approach was right. The reason your search bar is 
coming down to next line is that you gave it padding of 1em. If you change it to padding: 0em 1em; then everything will work accordingly.Refer to this link https://jsfiddle.net/osha90/z8erbr6h/

```
<div class="panel-heading">
<div style="float:left;vertical-align: center;">
<a type="button" class="btn btn-info">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-erase"></span><b> Search</b>
</a>
</div>
<div style="float:right;">
<a type="button" class="btn btn-warning">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-erase"></span><b> Clear</b>
</a>
</div>
<div style="overflow: hidden;padding:0em 1em;">
<input type="text" value="Enter your search here..." ng-model="searchText" style="width: 100%;"></input>
</div>
</div>
```